# ElementPlus UI: DatePicker range always get same from/to date

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using Vue3+ElementPlus UI. I need to have a date range component(as from/to date) on my page. I added one as below:

```
<template>
   <el-date-picker
      v-model="dates"
      type="daterange"
      range-separator="To"
      unlink-panels
      start-placeholder="Start date"
      end-placeholder="End date"
      value-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
      >
    </el-date-picker>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref,computed, reactive, provide, toRef, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { ElDatePicker } from 'element-plus'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Home',
  setup: function () {

    const dates = ref(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-31']);

     return {
         dates
     }
  }
})
</script>
```

Initially, as I setup the initial value for "dates", it's fine. But when i changed the date either in the from box or in the to box, both dates changed to the same value i.e. both show "2021-03-05".
Did I use it in a wrong way?
Btw even on it's office website the "from" and "to" dates are changed together

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I am having the same problem and it only happens when you use the value-format prop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to use events. These are my codes

```
 <div class="block">
<span class="demonstration">Date Range<br/></span>
<el-date-picker
  v-model="value2"
  type="datetimerange"
  :shortcuts="shortcuts"
  range-separator="To"
  start-placeholder="Start date"
  end-placeholder="End date"
  value-format="YYYY-MM-DD"
  @change="datePicked($event)"
  />
 </div>
 <script setup>
 import { ref } from 'vue'
 import store from '../store';
  
const value2 = ref('')
const datePicked=(event)=>{console.log('The first date is'+event[0]+" 
 and the second date is"+event[1])}
 </script>
```

Did it work out in the end? v-model treats the input as one component. I was stuck with a similar issue for hours. Use event like I did or a method